# Data type conversion in Hbase

Tags: apache-kafka, hbase, avro, apache-kafka-connect

A an using the Hbase StreamReactor Kafka Connector with this configuration

```
name=person-hbase 
connector.class=com.datamountaineer.streamreactor.connect.hbase.HbaseSinkConnector 
tasks.max=1 
topics=hbase-topic
connect.hbase.column.family=d
connect.hbase.kcql=INSERT INTO person SELECT * FROM hbase-topic PK firstName, lastName
```

Why are values sent from Kafka to HBase represented in this way?
`value=@\xB56\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00`

How to change it to normal readable way?

```
hbase(main):004:0* scan 'person'
ROW                                                  COLUMN+CELL
 Anna\x0AJones                                       column=d:age, timestamp=1463056888641, value=\x00\x00\x00\x1C
 Anna\x0AJones                                       column=d:firstName, timestamp=1463056888641, value=Anna
 Anna\x0AJones                                       column=d:income, timestamp=1463056888641, value=@\xB56\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00
 Anna\x0AJones                                       column=d:lastName, timestamp=1463056888641, value=Jones
 John\x0ASmith                                       column=d:age, timestamp=1463056693877, value=\x00\x00\x00\x1E
 John\x0ASmith                                       column=d:firstName, timestamp=1463056693877, value=John
 John\x0ASmith                                       column=d:income, timestamp=1463056693877, value=@\xB2\xDE\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00
 John\x0ASmith                                       column=d:lastName, timestamp=1463056693877, value=Smith
2 row(s) in 0.0260 seconds
```

Comment: If you used Kafka Connect, please show your configuration

Comment: You mean the hbase-sink.properties?
`name=person-hbase
connector.class=com.datamountaineer.streamreactor.connect.hbase.HbaseSinkConnector
tasks.max=1
topics=hbase-topic
connect.hbase.column.family=d
connect.hbase.kcql=INSERT INTO person SELECT * FROM hbase-topic PK firstName, lastName`

Comment: AFAIK, that output is to be expected. HBase only stores bytes, and you are just seeing ASCII representations of that data. See the documentation, https://lenses.stream/1.1/connectors/sink/hbase.html#check-for-records-in-hbase  Perhaps you have not used HBase before to know otherwise?